# UI: add buttons to Sidebar boxes

Tags: gui-design, buttons, sidebar, mac-os-x

I've got a window with a sidebar divided into several Boxes.

The boxes have different controls, sometimes arranged into scrollable tables.

UI looks ok to my users. Clean and simple.
[image]

**Now (the task) - I need to add small amount of buttons (1-3) to all the boxes.**

What I got is a button bar below each box which interferes with the adjacent title and makes the UI dense and overcrowded(see below). Please advice...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See if you can replace the buttons with icons and place them in title bar:

[image]

Comment: That's a good option. Maybe if there are several buttons could use a dropdown icon.

Answer (score 0):

inclusion of buttons might look dense in wireframes but by proper spacing and visual design we can make it look normal.

---

you can simplify the buttons by including simple buttons like

[image]

and

[image]

if possible you can accomodate some of these icons in the title bar.